# JavaScript isn’t working when linking .js file to .html file

Tags: javascript, html, progress-bar

I've been learning HTML, CSS & javascript these last few weeks. All the previous coding experience I've had is with C++ from my CS courses so I'm new to front end development.

I wrote some javascript in the HTML index page and the functions work properly. However, when I add it into an external .js file, the program stops working.

Here's the index.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css"/>
    <title> Progress Bar </title>
</head>
<body>
    <audio id="music" src="trax/coldWorld.wav" controls></audio>

    <div class="progress_bar" id="progress_bar">
        <div class="progressed" id="progressed"></div>
    </div>
</body>

<script src="/audio.js"></script>

</html>
```

The .js file:

```
    var music = document.getElementById('music');
    var progressed = document.getElementById('progressed');
    var progress_bar = document.getElementById('progress_bar');

    music.ontimeupdate = function(e) {
        progressed.style.width = Math.floor(music.currentTime *100 / music.duration) + "%";
    }

    progress_bar.onclick = function(e) {
        music.currentTime = ((e.offsetX / progress_bar.offsetWidth) * music.duration);
    }
```

Comment: is the path of JavaScript file correct ? Can you share folder structure ?

Answer (score -1):

You can try moving the script tag inside the body tag and correcting the relative path

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    ...
</head>
<body>
    ...
    <script src="./audio.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That was it! Thanks man. It's my first time implementing some javaScript :]